# How to call postman collections dynamically via newman commands or from selenium with java?

Tags: java, json, selenium, postman, newman

I have few postman collections (like CreateA.json, CreateB.json & many more) and I want to call these collections dynamically through newman several times as per sequence mentioned in the sheet. How can I call these packages in the given sequence?

CSV sheet sequence is:

- Row1 CreateA.json
- Row2 CreateB.json
- Row3 CreateA.json
- Row4 CreateB.json
- Row5 CreateA.json

Answer (score 0):

You can just write simple bash script which will run every collection one by one. To run collection several times you can use option '-i'.
eg. `newman run collection -e environment -n iterations_count`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the file structure, you can use the following scripts

**Case 1: A text file having all collection names on newline**

```
CreateA.json
CreateB.json
CreateC.json
```

Bash script to use:

```
cat file.txt | xargs -n1 newman run
```

**Case 2: A csv file  having all collection names on newline**

```
collectionName
CreateA.json
CreateB.json
CreateC.json
```

Bash script to use:

```
awk 'NR>1' file.csv | xargs -n1 newman run
```

**Case 3: A csv file  having multiple columns**

```
rowNum,collectionName
row1,CreateA.json
row2,CreateB.json
row3,CreateC.json
```

Bash script to use:

```
awk 'NR>1' test.csv | xargs -n1 | cut -d "," -f2 | xargs -n1 newman run
```

Explanation:

- xargs is used in building an execution pipeline from standard input. `newman` can't just accept the collection name from standard input, so using xargs to pass the name to it. Also using `-n1` to pass at most 1 line at a time to `newman`
- `awk 'NR>1' fileName` is simple just skipping the first line
- `cut -d "," -f2` is used to split the line on `,` and take the `2nd` value

Comment: Hi Harry, Very Thankful to you for the such a nice explanation but one thing more I want to know that How can I pass the required parameter for that postman collection through my another file? And it would be very helpful for me If you can explain how we can use no of columns using {awk 'NR>1' test.csv | xargs -n1 | cut -d "," -f2 | xargs -n1 newman run} command?

Comment: I am glad to be able to help. To pass parameters just use `newman run collection.json -d dataFileName.csv`  as mentioned here https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman#newman-run-collection-file-source-options

Comment: Also, I have already given a very basic explanation of the terms I have used. To learn more about them, just google each term separately and practice a little bit on them.